# Вебсокеты с условной подпиской

Tags: java, spring, websocket

Задача: есть клиенты, которые подписываются у сервера на события, удовлетворяющие некоторым параметрам (скажем, событие по объекту, лежащему в некотором прямоугольнике). Параметры подписки у каждого клиента различные. При возникновении события, сервер отправляет его тем клиентам, которые его ждут.

Реализация нужна на асинхронных веб-сокетах.

Теперь вопросы: из библиотек, которые поддерживают вебсокеты, а нашел только JavaEE и Spring. Есть ли что-то легкое в виде надстройки над nio2 или нужно тащить Spring?

Если Spring, то как это реализовать на нем? Я нашел только работу с броадкастами и работу в режиме запрос-ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чем не нравится библиотека из Tomcat? есть хорошая библиотека http://tootallnate.github.io/Java-WebSocket/

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде оно. Сегодня пощупаю

Comment: Скопировал SimpleServer из примера. В браузере делаю `new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/');`  На сервере штатно отрабатывается `onOpen`, а в браузере срабатывают `onerror` с объектом `{isTrusted: true}` и `onclose` с пустым объектом

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov у меня так 


 con = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/WS_server"); а на сервере public class WS_Server extends WebSocketServer {...
у тебя не каспер случаем?

Comment: Взлетело. По ошибке прописал в JS процедуру закрытия сокета на кнопку коннект. В итоге сокет открывался и тут же закрывался

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov если есть интерес - могу поделиться наработками.

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде, все понятно

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov ээээ,там не так всё просто, если что  обращайся опыт с ws почти с начала из появления....